# Why isn't Highcharts showing the date formatted on x Axis?

Tags: highcharts

[Look at this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pgschr/tom1xjy4/1/), even though the date is formatted with `day: '%e of %Y'` it still appears in ISO format.

This is the javascript:

```
var xAxis = {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            day: '%e of %Y'
        }
    };

xAxis.categories = [];

for (var i=1;i<=10;i++){
   var d = new Date(2015,3,i);  
   xAxis.categories[i] = d;
 }

$('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: xAxis,
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1]
    }]
});
```

Comment: You've got to decide on `categories` or `datetime`. Both doesn't make sense. In essence you are here just displaying the `toString` method of the `Date` object.

Comment: I have to show data of 10 non consecutive dates, would that be datetime or categories?

Comment: `datetime`. You will need for your data to be pairs of `[<time in milliseconds>, <value>]`.

Comment: Well, `datetime` given that you want to represent them as non-consecutive as well. If you want to show them side by side, while being separated by differing amounts of time you could still use `category`, but normally I'd say `datetime` is the best fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ondkloss said in the comments you should either use **`datetime`** or **`categories`**. **datetime** would be the better choice in your case. You can use something like this:

```
var dataPlusDates = [];
var data = [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1];

for (var i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; i++) {
    var d = Date.UTC(2015,3,i);
    dataPlusDates.push([d, data[i]]);
 }

$('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: xAxis,
    series: [{
        data: dataPlusDates
    }]
});
```

The data in series should be in the format of [**time in milliseconds**, **value**] again as Ondkloss said. **`time in milliseconds`** could be calculated using **`Date.UTC(year, month, day)`**. So I changed your for loop and created that format for you and put it in **series.data**. Here's the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tom1xjy4/2/).

Comment: [In this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Pgschr/tom1xjy4/3/) I have a date that is not consecutive. Highcharts plot the points correctly but doesn't draw a line, even if it's a line chart, why is that?

Comment: It was because of the **`i`** in the for loop. **data** start from 0, but i starts from 1, therefore the last data (data[10]) return undefined. Here's the correct fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tom1xjy4/4/